# Parsing JSON data & Load it in Fragments

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, fragment

Excuse me  i already had an Application which Display my Sites articles and Novels in Android the codes in Main Activity to display  only one Section

i create in the site 5 sections every section had a different content
i Added items to Navigation Drawers and i defined the fragment and its connectivity   but the Problem in the Code i failed so
 i want to know how to load Data in 4 Fragments

RecyclerViewAdapter.class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;


public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private int previousPosition = 0;
    private List<com.salim3dd.recyclerview_moredata.List_Item> List_Item;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<List_Item> list_Item, Context context) {
        List_Item = list_Item;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        View menu1 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.row_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MenuItemViewHolder(menu1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        MenuItemViewHolder menuItemHolder = (MenuItemViewHolder) holder;

        menuItemHolder.TextName.setText(List_Item.get(position).getStory());

        Picasso.with(context).load(List_Item.get(position).getImg_link()).into(menuItemHolder.imageView);

        menuItemHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, List_Item.get(position).getStory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


                if (position > previousPosition) { //scrolling DOWN
                    AnimationUtil.animate(menuItemHolder, true);

                } else { // scrolling UP

                    AnimationUtil.animate(menuItemHolder, false);
                }
                previousPosition = position;


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != List_Item ? List_Item.size() : 0);
    }

    protected class MenuItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView cardView;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView TextName;

        public MenuItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextName);
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.salim3dd.recyclerview_moredata.CheckInternetConnection;
import com.salim3dd.recyclerview_moredata.List_Item;
import com.salim3dd.recyclerview_moredata.R;
import com.salim3dd.recyclerview_moredata.RecyclerViewAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerView_dAdapter;
    public List<List_Item> listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.m_RecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        recyclerView_dAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(listItem, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerView_dAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if (gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == listItem.size() - 1) {
                    Get_All_Users(listItem.get(listItem.size()-1).getId());
                }

            }
        });

        Get_All_Users(0);
    }

    public void Get_All_Users(int limit) {

        CheckInternetConnection cic = new CheckInternetConnection(getApplicationContext());
        Boolean Ch = cic.isConnectingToInternet();
        if (!Ch) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "Data Link" + limit
                    ,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                JSONArray jsonArray_usersS = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("All_storys");

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_usersS.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject responsS = jsonArray_usersS.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int id = responsS.getInt("id");
                                    String story = responsS.getString("story_name");
                                    String img_link = responsS.getString("img_link");

                                    listItem.add(new List_Item(id, story, img_link));

                                }
                                recyclerView_dAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            queue.add(stringRequest);
            stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);


        }
    }
}
```

List Items.class

```
public class List_Item {

    public int id;
    public String story;
    public String img_link;

    public List_Item(int id, String story, String img_link) {
        this.id = id;
        this.story = story;
        this.img_link = img_link;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getStory() {
        return story;
    }

    public String getImg_link() {
        return img_link;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see how you set up "4 fragments" what does it mean?

Comment: which fragment? are you want to load the data in ViewPager?

Comment: the app is contain only one section which is MainActivity i will add navigation drawer and add items to to the Navigation Drawer  then the fragments   the question is how to load the data in the fragments